# Where is my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` on systemd?

Tags: systemd, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

Before `systemd`, I could just simply edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file to add my desired network with pre-shared key:

```
$ cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf 
network={
    ssid="TPLINK"
    psk="My secret pre-shared key"
}
```

But on `systemd`, where is my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`? How can I edit my network and pre-shared key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man wpa_supplicant`:

> QUICK START
>
> First, make a configuration file, e.g.  `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`, that
>   describes the networks you are
>   interested in.  See  wpa_supplicant.conf(5) for details.

Alternatively, you could create the file at `/etc/wpa_supplicant/yourconfig.conf`.

Comment: I was reading the `man` page, but I think I looked over that sentence. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

From the archwiki:

> At boot (systemd)

The wpa_supplicant package provides multiple systemd service files:

`wpa_supplicant.service` - uses D-Bus, recommended for NetworkManager users.

`wpa_supplicant@interface.service` - accepts the interface name as an argument and starts the wpa_supplicant daemon for this interface. It reads a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-interface.conf configuration file.

`wpa_supplicant-nl80211@interface.service` - also interface specific, but explicitly forces the nl80211 driver (see below). The configuration file path is /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-nl80211-interface.conf.

`wpa_supplicant-wired@interface.service` - also interface specific, uses the wired driver. The configuration file path is /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wired-interface.conf.

To enable wireless at boot, enable an instance of one of the above services on a particular wireless interface. For example, enable the wpa_supplicant@interface systemd unit.

Now choose and enable an instance of a service to obtain an ip address for the particular interface as indicated in the #Overview. For example, enable the dhcpcd@interface systemd unit.

So it seems you would need to rename the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant-*interfacename*.conf`. Find the interface name using ifconfig, ip, or something similar.

Then `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@interfacename.service` to run it at startup.

If you want DHCP, also enable SystemD's DHCP unit for the interface `systemctl enable dhcpcd@interfacename`

Additionally, I would suggest if at all possible to switch to a more sane init system if at all possible ;)

Comment: What would be a more sane init system?

Comment: Anything but systemd, which appears to be aiming to replace the entire userland with its own special copies of everything, wrapped up into one giant binary, in the style of busybox.  Systemd does have some great ideas for init scripts, but it shouldn't be taking over the world - that's totally against the Unix philosophy of "do one thing, and do it well".

Comment: A system stable on the time scale of decades, so I don't have to re-learn system configuration every ten years or so